# background-image not working with local images?

Tags: html, css, image

I tried everything to make background image display with my local images. I know that I have the correct image location. because if I use content:url(); it works.

Background-image also works with a url image location from the internet. But it will not render with my local image. I have tried every possible location and it will not render.

This is the path to css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/myCSS.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

my images folder is in the same path as my css folder.

The following is the HTML code:

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>start here</p>
   <a href="#" class="angelhack"></a>
  </div>
```

and now the CSS:`enter code here`

```
  .col-md-2 .angelhack {
  height: 65px;
  width: 188px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(myPicture.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  }

 .col-md-2 .angelhack:hover {
  background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SWLJdR2_YzE/TWB-
EvvBWpI/AAAAAAAAA6U/MVtkwJXED88/s320/donkey.png');
  }
```

Before anyone labels this a repeat question, I have searched all the answers to this question on StackOverFlow and have followed all the suggestions and I still cannot get the picture to render. I know the picture is in the correct location because with Chrome and content:url(); the image works. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post the code with the problem where you have given the local image path not the one that works according to you. Personally I think you are having issue with your local path.

Comment: can you check devtools if it's showing any errors?

Comment: checked dev tools, no errors.

Comment: If you are noticing that it weirdly is not showing then it might be getting caught by your **ad blocker**. Turn your adblocker off and name the image wisely ie. don't include the word `ad`

Answer (score 5):

Your missing your `""` quotes

```
background-image: url(myPicture.jpg);
```

**With**

```
background-image: url("myPicture.jpg");
```

**try,**

```
background: url("myPicture.jpg");
```

**Also,**

- Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
- Is the image in a directory **below**?
- Is the image in a directory **above**?

By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories. Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a look at my primitive example:
[image]

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward

Comment: Thank you for the path's explanation, you saved my project!

Answer (score 1):

I have used `background` instead of `background-image` and it's working fine. and it assumes that pic is in the same folder as your html.

```
.col-md-2 .angelhack {
  height: 65px;
  width: 188px;
  display: block;
  background: url("myPicture.jpg") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Overlooked that the file path for the url wasn't in double quotes.

Change:

```
 background-image: url("myPicture.jpg") no-repeat 0px 0px;
```

To:

```
 background-image: url("myPicture.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.

```
.col-md-2 .angelhack {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat;
//Set your path in the double quote's 
  }
```

Comment: I tried that. That is the exact path to my image. It is in the image folder. But I also tried making a copy of it and putting it in my css folder and in my html folder.

Comment: Can you update your question code with the path which is giving you this problem so we can work using that.

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem was the way you wrote the `background-image`

Instead of writing it like this

`background-image: url('mypicture.jpg') no-repeat 50px 50px; //the size isn't good there`

Do it like this

```
background-image: url('mypicture.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: 50px 50px;
```

It will appear like this